# Time issues in ffmpeg script (MP4 to MP3 conversion)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I use the code below as script on my Debian PC to create MP3 files from MP4 video files for adding to podcast app on android phone.

But each time I click pause/forward time position (not indication) is set up in random way after resuming. Please help improve the code below to solve this problem.

```
for f in *.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:a -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k "${f%.mp4}.mp3"
done
for f in *.mp3; do
  vbrfix -always -makevbr -lameinfo "$f" "${f%.mp3}.mp3"
  rm -rf vbrfix.log vbrfix.tmp
done
```

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Bash question that has to do with programming and development, and includes program control flow (and not just how to run a command).

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add the `-write_xing 0` output option to your `ffmpeg` command? Does the issue occur if you use `lame` instead to encode the MP3 file? (You can pipe from `ffmpeg` to `lame`: several examples are here on this site.)

Comment: LordNeckbeard, -write_xing didn't help but I've solved the problem by using -q:a instead of -b:a and without vbrfix.